# Callback function when PEPPER's tablet gets touched, only works correctly the first time

Tags: python, callback, signals, robotics, pepper

I've been stuck trying to make a simple "yes or no" button on a PEPPER's tablet.

I'm doing it by just showing a image with "yes-no" and just catching the X coordinate when someone touches the tablet with a tabletService.onTouchDown function.

The problem is that it works perfectly the first time but i need it to work for multiple answers and after the second time i call the functions it "skips" waiting for the callback as if it already got it.

This is the function that catches the touch;
It just checks X coordinate of the touch and returns 1 or 0 depending if it was made in the left or right side of the screen:

```
def getAnswer():
global ans
showIm()
try: 
    signalID=0
    ans = -1

    def callback(x, y): #it doesn't enter the callback on the second time
        global ans
        print "coordinate are x: ", x, " y: ", y
        if x > 640:
            ans = 0
        elif x < 640:
            ans = 1
            
        app.stop()
        return ans
    print(signalID)
    signalID = tabletService.onTouchDown.connect(callback)
    print(signalID)
    app.run()

    tabletService.onTouchDown.disconnect(signalID)
    return ans

except Exception, e:
    print "Error was: ", e
```

And this is the function calling "getAnswer" twice:

```
def start():
global messagetosend, context, ans

outer = "Test Si o No"
produce_outer(outer)

ans = getAnswer()

if ans == 1:
    outer = "Hai cliccato SI"
    produce_outer(outer)

elif ans == 0:
    outer = "Hai cliccato NO"
    produce_outer(outer)


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ans = getAnswer()
#tabletService.resetTablet()

if ans == 1:
    outer = "Hai cliccato SI"
    produce_outer(outer)

elif ans == 0:
    outer = "Hai cliccato NO"
    produce_outer(outer)

tabletService.hideImage()
```

Even tried a function that should reset the tablet cache and whatnot but it doesn't seem to be helping so i erased it.
The weird thing is that if you "spam click" the screen, before the program skips it, the callback works but can't really ask people to spam click it.

p.s. i know the code is probably dirty but i'm in "trying to make this thing work mode" so i'm not really focusing on making it elegant right now.
p.p.s. don't know if you need the part of the code where i set up the connection, just let me now.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: This "app.stop()" in you callback, seems weird to me. If you stop something, it won't work next time...

Comment: Tried to remove the app.stop() but it just doesn't exit the callback anymore, not even with the return

Comment: There's no reason the callback doesn't exit, it should be something else, like you think it doesn't exit, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

`app.stop()` stops all NAOqi signals from being processed.